# How to use the Root Locus design method to improve the transient response of my system?

Tags: control, control-system, matlab

By closing the loop, I need to design a controller in the feedforward path to minimise the effects of the two pairs of dominant poles of the 5th order transfer function. Use a pole-zero cancellation technique on a root locus diagram and if need be introduce  an integrator to eliminate the steady state error. Proceed to determine a suitable gain K that satisfies the following design specifications:

```
Less than 5% overshoot
Less than 2s settling time
Steady State Error Minimized
```

---

From the above performance requirements, I calculated where the closed loop poles should be:

[image]

```
desired_poles = [-2.6 + 1i*2.39, -2.6 - 1i*2.39, -100, -120, -110];
```

My 5th order system is defined as follows:

```
num = [0.0001 10];
den = [0.005 5 0.66 61 2.1 10];
tf = tf(num, den)
[A, B, C, D] = tf2ss(num, den);
e = eig(A)
sisotool(tf);
step(tf);
```

where:

```
e =

   1.0e+02 *

  -9.9990 + 0.0000i
  -0.0004 + 0.0347i
  -0.0004 - 0.0347i
  -0.0002 + 0.0041i
  -0.0002 - 0.0041i
```

and the step response is :

[image]

and using `sisotool()` I get a different step response:

[image]

and zoomed in with design requirements inputted/ I am unable to come up with any form of compensator which does not result in the two rightmost poels going unstable:

[image]

For example, if I add a lead compensator with a real zero at -2 and a real pole at -5 I get a reshaped root locus which passes through the desired area. However, the two furthest right poles will immediately go unstable as soon as I start moving the other poles around.

[image]

---

I am now trying to determine which compensator is needed to achieve the desired results.

- Going through MATLAB [official docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/root-locus-design.html), the process seems to involve trial and error inside the `sisotool()` app.

**How can I design a compensator to give me the above poles which yield desired results?**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: They are using a different step value as stimulus.

Comment: How can I make sure that the `sisotool` step value is set to 1? I see `Sample Time: 0` and `Value: 1` in the preview tab on the left.

Comment: What, exactly, is the question? This currently looks like you've gone down a wrong path and hit a wall.

Comment: @Chu, the whole question is presented before the first line separator. I then give my fifth order transfer function. That is all the information I am given and the rest is what I have done so far to try to solve. If anything is unclear please let me know and will do my best to update

Comment: So were the TF parameters given to 10 sig figs in the original question?

Comment: I leave 10 significant figures for accuracy purposes, but yes that is the correct transfer function which I need to work with. I will edit since I agree that this is not well presented.

Comment: 10 sig figs is NOT accuracy, it's obscuring the picture. Give the original 5th order TF as posed in the question.

Comment: ... eg does 61.01102010 **definitely** lie between 61.011020104 and 61.011020096?

Comment: Are those plots for the open-loop TF or closed-loop TF?

Comment: Those plots are of the open-loop TF and as the question states I need to close the loop to get the desired response. The poles I calculated are the closed loop poles.

Comment: You didn't use the hint in the question, about using an integrator.

Comment: True, I didn't use any integrator yet, but shouldn't that come after I've added the compensator? As I understand it, I first need to take care of the overshoot and settling time, by adding a compensator and then proceed to lower steady state error.

Comment: Ok, that's your choice, of course.

Comment: What I am confused about is that I have the desired poles, `gzita`,`wn` and all the required parameters but I am still unable to construct a compensator using the pole-zero cancellation technique. I must be overlooking something important.

Comment: How do you cancel a pole at s = -5, for example? Are you cancelling the open loop poles or closed loop poles?

Comment: As I understand, root loci can be reshaped using a compensator so that a pair of dominant CL poles can be placed in the desired location. This is done by adding poles and zeros to the OL transfer function and forcing the root loci to pass through the desired CL poles. So technically we are reshaping/cancelling the closed loop poles by altering the open loop transfer function.

Comment: Right. So back to my earlier question: how do you cancel a pole at ... etc.

Comment: You need to understand that the overshoot is solely defined for second order systems or systems that can be approximated as 2nd system.

Comment: I believe that my system can be approximated by a second order system. This is done if I have only a pair of dominant poles, which I have found in the hand written working above. `desired_poles = [-2.6 + 1i*2.39, -2.6 - 1i*2.39, -100, -120, -110]; `